# Excel won't show the workbooks worksheets

Tags: vba, hidden, worksheet, excel

I have an Excel Workbook containing three worksheets. However all sheets seem to be hidden dispite that their visibility is set to xlSheetVisible (Found by looking at the worksheet properties in the VBA editor).

This is what I have tried so far to solve the problem.

- Searched Google for help, but all similar problems have been solved by changing the Visibility from xlSheetHidden to xlSheetVisible. But in my case that setting is already set to xlVisible.

  - By using VBA I have tried to activate a sheet without any result.

By reading this you might have guessed that I am able to see and access the worksheets from the VBA editor.

Despite that looking at the normal Excel userinterface, all buttons are disabled and clicking at the office/file button in the topleft corner doesn't allow me to save the workbook. However if I make any changes to the VBA itself and tries to close the workbook then Excel asks whether or not I would like to save the workbook.

Comment: if the workbook is an add in (.xlam) then you will have to rename it to an xlsm to be able to see it

Comment: Just my thought, but the file is saved as in xlsm format and the property IsAddin is set to false.

Comment: make sure that the Workbook is not protected for Structure: Tools>Protection>Workbook

Comment: All options available at the ribbon are disabled. It seems like Excel wont recognize that a workbook is a open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything you describe leads me to believe you're hiding the **workbook window**, not the worksheets. When a workbook window is hidden, all the sheets become hidden and much of the functionality from the toolbar greys out.

In the Visual Basic Editor, you'd also be able to see all of the worksheets and their visibility would be `xlVisible`, yet they cannot be seen on the screen. This is because they ARE visible, but the window which displays them is not.

Please try clicking the **View** tab in the toolbar, and then under the **Window** pane, click **Unhide**.

[image]

If this doesn't work, then try toggling visibility of the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this may really be your problem...

http://vbadud.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/hide-sheet-tabs-using-vba-hide-excel.html

Comment: When I look at the Advanced tab Excel states that there is no workbooks open, so I am not allowed to make that change.

Comment: Apologies, it maybe as others have suggested then, in the VBE window, select "ThisWorkbook" from the project explorer.  Press F4 to ensure properties are visible and find the property labelled "IsAddin", ensure this is False and see if you can see your worksheets now.

Comment: I've just double checked and that setting is set to false :/